# Excluding one category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blog-post

I just started out using wordpress as a CMS. On the site I have 2 pages I want different posts to show on. So far I understand this small code to post only one particular category one a page (when put infront of the loop:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=8&showposts=5');?>
```

But what do I write when I need to exclude this category on my blog-page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a minus to it. Example:

```
query_posts('cat=-3');
```

Comment: But will it still post the rest of the post categories that way?

Comment: Maybe then better use tagging than categories and just tag the posts you want or don't want. More info on the query_post: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

Comment: Thanks mate... can't believe i didn't think of that site before.

Answer (score 1):

You should only include the loop/category you want displayed on each page. Meaning you should have an index page and your secondary page should be a separate file within your template file. Then edit your categories accordingly.

index.php - query_posts('cat=BLOG&showposts=5');

other.php - query_posts('cat=OTHER&showposts=5');

Then create your page within the administration panel accordingly.