# Wordpress exclude category from blog in twenty twelve template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been googling around for an answer on how to exclude a category from my blog, without using a plugin.

I came up with this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-2'); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

But this doesn't exclude blog postings with a category ID of 2. Can it be clarified why?

Comment: `query_posts` should never be used. Use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding one category in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419309/excluding-one-category-in-wordpress)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-2');
```

Comment: `query_posts` should never be used. Use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query`

Comment: where do I put this code? Its not working

Comment: @PieterGoosen I absolutely agree either **WP_Query** or **pre_get_posts** should be used, but the question itself contained **query_posts** therefore I just made it to work.